# Scanner will take user input but will not find the file

Tags: java, runtime, java.util.scanner

This is a program to read a file and print out the file with some of the text edited. The code will compile the issue is that it will read the users input  but will say file is not found when the file is there. I feel like I am missing something. I am brand new at this so go easy on me.

Comment: May I ask what is in the file?

Comment: Not that will solve your problem but you should probably change `if (args[0] != null)` to `if (args.length>0)`. If user will not put any argument while starting your app `args[0]` will not exist because array length will be 0, so you will get IndexOutOfBoundException for `args[0]`.

Comment: Anyway where is file you want to read placed? What value you pass while running your program? From which directory you are running your program?

Comment: @Tdorno The code is to read more code and but numbers with the { and } and add numbers to the end so they match up. For example  {3  }3  then it will add 2 to the next {2  }2 and then add 1 to the next { it is to match up the curly braces to see which ones close what

Comment: @user2921727 Does the file contain Strings? Ints? Chars? All 3? You're reading everything as a String without handling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      //  if (args[0] != null)
            readFile();
    }

    public static void readFile() { // Method to read file

        Scanner inFile = null;
        String out = "";
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter file name");
            String filename = input.next();
            File in = new File(filename); // ask for the file name
            inFile = new Scanner(in);


            int count = 0;
            while (inFile.hasNextLine()) { // reads each line
                String line = inFile.nextLine();


                for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                    char ch = line.charAt(i);
                    out = out + ch;

                    if (ch == '{') {
                        count = count + 1;
                        out = out + " " + count;
                    } else if (ch == '}') {
                        out = out + " " + count;
                        if (count > 0) {
                            count = count - 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: this helps but it gets me back to where I started. The goal of this was to take the users input for the file name so any file could be tested with this code

Comment: @user2921727 Ah, see edit. All you needed to include was a simple scanner to ask for input.

Comment: it works but I need to do it with the try catch statments I had before and can not have the throws file exception in the main method. What do I do then

Comment: that was the goal of this assignment. To do it without anything in the main method

Comment: Hh ok, well logically you should be able to know where you need to implement the `try-catch`. I mean I don't want to do the whole assignment for you..

Comment: did but the problem is the inFile.Close(); keeps saying is saying it is not matched to anything

Comment: Update the question and I'll take a quick look at it within the hour.

Comment: does nothing with the file input

Comment: @user2921727 Thats b/c in this code snippet nothing is done with the input. Thats up to you.

Comment: I want it to go through the code and parse what is needed. That takes me back to my original question. How do I get it to do that something with the input

Comment: I need it to read the users input and complete the task but if the user inputs the wrong file name the error will pop up. Thats what my end goal is

Comment: @user2921727 Originally your code wasn't reading the file at all. This fixes that, for your other request I recommend you ask a newer question.

Comment: @user2921727 I found your issue, you kept resetting out in the while loop causing all of the inputs to not be stored in the String. My final edit works, it's now up to you to handle the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to find where `Scanner` looking to find your file. And you should be sure your file is located here.