# Using scanner to take input from txt file and find most common letter not working

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class extraCredit{
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("decrypt.txt"));
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            int tempCount = 0;
            int maxCount = 0;
            char maxLetter = 'a';
            String alphabet = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";
            for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length() - 1 ; i++){
                char lLetter = alphabet.charAt(i);
                i++;
                char uLetter = alphabet.charAt(i); 
                for(int a = 0; a < line.length(); a++){     
                    if(line.charAt(a) == lLetter | line.charAt(a) == uLetter){
                        tempCount ++;
                    }
                }
                if(tempCount > maxCount){
                    maxCount = tempCount;
                    maxLetter = lLetter;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(maxLetter + maxCount);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for an extra credit assignment. The goal of this program is to say what letter appears the most frequently. I make a string from the one and only line from the decrypt.txt. My logic in this is to make a temporary count to keep track of the first letter then go onto b and if that has a higher temp count then it is now the maximum count. I put all the letters uppercase and lower case next to each other so I could make the lLetter and uLetter for lower case letter and upper case letter using .charAt(i). At the end it should output what had the highest count. This java file compiles but it does not output anything. Could anyone help me figure out what is wrong. I feel like this logic is sound. Thank you.

Kyviv zj r sreb kyrk tivuzkj pfli rttflek vrty dfiezex nzky £86,400. Zk triizvj fmvi ef srcretv wifd urp kf urp. Vmvip vmvezex uvcvkvj nyrkvmvi grik fw kyv srcretv pfl wrzcvu kf ljv ulizex kyv urp. Nyrk nflcu pfl uf? Uirn flk RCC FW ZK, fw tflijv!!!! Vrty fw lj yrj jlty r sreb. Zkj erdv zj KZDV. Vmvip dfiezex, zk tivuzkj pfl nzky 86,400 jvtfeuj. Vmvip ezxyk zk nizkvj fww, rj cfjk, nyrkvmvi fw kyzj pfl yrmv wrzcvu kf zemvjk kf xffu gligfjv. Zk triizvj fmvi ef srcretv. Zk rccfnj ef fmviuirwk. Vrty urp zk fgvej r evn rttflek wfi pfl. Vrty ezxyk zk sliej kyv ivdrzej fw kyv urp. Zw pfl wrzc kf ljv kyv urp’j uvgfjzkj, kyv cfjj zj pflij. Kyviv zj ef xfzex srtb. Kyviv zj ef uirnzex rxrzejk kyv “kfdfiifn.” Pfl dljk czmv ze kyv givjvek fe kfurp’j uvgfjzkj. Zemvjk zk jf rj kf xvk wifd zk kyv lkdfjk ze yvrcky, yrggzevjj, reu jlttvjj! Kyv tcftb zj ileezex. Drbv kyv dfjk fw kfurp.

This is the text but it is all on one line in the txt file.

If possible could you try to help me figure out why the one I made does not work instead of writing out new programs. The ones I have seen contain many tools we have not learned yet. Thankyou.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class extraCredit2{
public static void main(String args[])
throws FileNotFoundException{
    //Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("decrypt.txt"));
    //while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        //String line = sc.nextLine();
        String line = "ashdbskjdbfkjsnfdkfjssjaandkjbsdkfjnsndkfkjnfwjneijfnweifjwbshdbfjhbaskjdnaskdjbdf";
        int tempCount = 0;
        int maxCount = 0;
        String maxLetter = "a";
        String alphabet = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length() - 1; i++) {
            tempCount = 0;
            String lLetter = alphabet.charAt(i) + "";
            i++;
            String uLetter = alphabet.charAt(i) + "";
            for (int a = 0; a < line.length(); a++) {
                if ((line.charAt(a) + "").equals(lLetter) | (line.charAt(a) + "").equals(uLetter)) {
                    tempCount++;
                }
            }
            if (tempCount > maxCount) {
                maxCount = tempCount;
                maxLetter = lLetter;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxLetter + maxCount);
    //}
}
}
```

This new code works out, but i commented out the .txt file part and just made a different string. Thank you all.

Comment: Please learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: Sample of similar program was implemented here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600409/scanner-will-take-user-input-but-will-not-find-the-file?rq=1. Also, make sure you place your file into the same folder with your class

Comment: Make sure the file exists (in the location the program is looking - and keep in mind that it might be case sensitive on some systems), make sure the file is not empty, and make sure no exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: i have them both in the same folder. there are no error or exceptions that show up. I compile it with command prompt using javac which after working on it for a while now does not have any exceptions, but when I run it, it outputs nothing. I have taken in input from files like this before, I think the problem is the for loops going through the strings and comparing them.

Comment: 1) convert the input to lowercase so you don't have to check both upper and lower cases (with `line.toLowerCase()`. 2) you never reset `tempCount` back to 0 so it is always higher for the next letter. This should happen every iteration.

Comment: thank you the line.toLowerCase would simplify it. Yeah i figured the tempCount problem already

Comment: The only way I see for this program to produce no output is if you are either throwing an exception or if the file contains no data. The most likely reason to throw an exception would be if the file is not found or not readable. My first thought is that the file is not in the default directory. Try giving a full path to the file. If that doesn't work, use a debugger or add some println statements to see if you get past opening the file, and if you successfully read a line. You also might put in a try/catch block and print a message if you hit the catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
public class extraCredit{
    public static void main(String args[])
throws FileNotFoundException{
    Map<String,Integer> letCounts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("decrypt.txt"));
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        for(String s : line.split(""))
            if(letCounts.containsKey(s))
                letCounts.put(s,letCounts.get(s)+1);
            else
                letCounts.put(s,1);
    }

    int maxCount=0;
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : letCounts.entrySet())
    {
        maxCount=Math.max(maxCount, e.getValue());
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : letCounts.entrySet())
    {
        if(e.getValue()==maxCount)
            System.out.println(e.getKey()+e.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

**Updated loop**

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        int tempCount = 0;
        int maxCount = 0;
        String maxLetter = "a";
        String alphabet = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length() ; i++) {
            tempCount = 0;
            String lLetter = alphabet.charAt(i) + "";

            for (int a = 0; a < line.length(); a++) {
                if ((line.charAt(a) + "").equals(lLetter)) {
                    tempCount++;
                }
            }
            if (tempCount > maxCount) {
                maxCount = tempCount;
                maxLetter = lLetter;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxLetter + maxCount);
    }
```

this gives

`v72` for

```
Kyviv zj r sreb kyrk tivuzkj pfli rttflek vrty dfiezex nzky £86,400. Zk triizvj fmvi ef srcretv wifd urp kf urp. Vmvip vmvezex uvcvkvj nyrkvmvi grik fw kyv srcretv pfl wrzcvu kf ljv ulizex kyv urp. Nyrk nflcu pfl uf? Uirn flk RCC FW ZK, fw tflijv!!!! Vrty fw lj yrj jlty r sreb. Zkj erdv zj KZDV. Vmvip dfiezex, zk tivuzkj pfl nzky 86,400 jvtfeuj. Vmvip ezxyk zk nizkvj fww, rj cfjk, nyrkvmvi fw kyzj pfl yrmv wrzcvu kf zemvjk kf xffu gligfjv. Zk triizvj fmvi ef srcretv. Zk rccfnj ef fmviuirwk. Vrty urp zk fgvej r evn rttflek wfi pfl. Vrty ezxyk zk sliej kyv ivdrzej fw kyv urp. Zw pfl wrzc kf ljv kyv urp’j uvgfjzkj, kyv cfjj zj pflij. Kyviv zj ef xfzex srtb. Kyviv zj ef uirnzex rxrzejk kyv “kfdfiifn.” Pfl dljk czmv ze kyv givjvek fe kfurp’j uvgfjzkj. Zemvjk zk jf rj kf xvk wifd zk kyv lkdfjk ze yvrcky, yrggzevjj, reu jlttvjj! Kyv tcftb zj ileezex. Drbv kyv dfjk fw kfurp.
```

Comment: i do not doubt that this might work, but you are using many tools that we have not been introduced to in class like line.split containsKey Map.Entry. Thank you for trying with this though.

Comment: i ran your code for the input `alsfbouwdbnvubwquovnoqwnv'oipnwovnoiqenguojivnweoivnu4bnwuwn4roviunevoui4nrbwouvwnvemk` and i see `201`. is this the expected output

Comment: I meant to have it output the actual letter then the max so this probably adds the int value of the char to the int maxCount what about System.out.println((char) (maxLetter) + maxCount); on mine it outputs nothing, maybe I do have the file in the wrong place.

Comment: that still prints out `201`. try using strings instead of characters

Comment: i see. 82 is definitely wrong, I think it is because the temp count is never reset to 0 at the beginning of each iteration of the outer for loop. I am familiar with .equals, but I have never encountered .equals.IgnoreCase

Comment: `.equals.IgnoreCase` just treats upper and lowercase as same

Comment: I see, but then that defeats the purpose of me making two variables lLetter and uLetter. though if I do what you said it would work I would just need one variable for the letter.

Comment: yes, you just need one variable. see the updated code

Comment: so now for `alsfbouwdbnvubwquovnoqwnv'oipnwovnoiqenguojivnweoivnu4bnwuwn4roviunevoui4nrbwouvwnvemk` i get `n13` which is what i was getting using the Map, so it is correct. i am also using `.equals` since it looks like you need to treat upper and lowercase as different

Comment: Ah, I managed to make it work before I saw you update it. but in your updated code there is not longer the if ((line.charAt(a) + "").equals(lLetter) | (line.charAt(a) + "").equals(uLetter)) you just have checking if there is lLetter. Why did you take out the uLetter? check my updated code at the top. Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ExtraCredit {

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String line = "this is a test";
    String[] splitLine = line.split("");
    HashMap<String,Integer> lettersMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    // Load HashMap with letters and the number of appearances
    for (int i = 0; i < splitLine.length; i++) {
        String letter = splitLine[i];
        if (!letter.equals("")) {
            if (lettersMap.containsKey(letter)) {
                int currentValue = lettersMap.get(letter);
                lettersMap.put(letter, ++currentValue);
            } else {
                lettersMap.put(letter, 1);
            }   
        }
    }
    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> mapIterator = lettersMap.entrySet().iterator();
    int highestValue = 0;
    String highestLetter = new String();
    while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, Integer> pair = mapIterator.next();
        if (pair.getValue() > highestValue) {
            highestValue = pair.getValue();
            highestLetter = pair.getKey();
        }           
        mapIterator.remove();
    }
    System.out.println("Letter: "+highestLetter+" "+"Times: "+highestValue);
}
```

}

This one should work!

Comment: thank you for typing this out but this uses many tools I am unfamiliar with